# Unable to use the google map map eventhough i got the API key

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-location

I have got the API key but still I am unable to open the google map in my project. my requirement is I have to get the current location and nearby hospital details in my app using google map and I want the list of hospitals near to that place in increasing order as per the distance. after clicking on my one of the hospital we can able to show the navigable path from current place to that particular hospital. Please find the UI part below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guWCu.jpg) Please help me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried you code and Stack trace if any.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let me ask you, What you had done till now ? Because based on your coding, Any developer can suggest you. Any How , Please Follow this..

**Define XML such like**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Initialize you google map in MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap googleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
```

}

**And Most Important Define your Manifest File properly with all permissions**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="packagename"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<permission
    android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="packagename.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Goolge API Key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBZMlkOv4sj-M5JO9p6wksdax4TEjDVLgo" />
</application>
```

Comment: also add these in your manifest under <application> tag

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />